# 502 gateway when a excel file upload happens for second time in NodeJs with Nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, multer

I have a webapp running in angular 7 with nodejs and mongodb with nginx hosted in ec2.

I have a API where users can bulk-upload data's into their profiles, API is written and it works fine in postman and ARC.

When integrated with app, it uploads and scripts runs successfully but when i try again with same file or different file its giving 502 bad gateway, i tried hitting another API before second upload, with different name, logout and login.. Still it gives me 502 gateway. Unless i restart my server i'm unable to upload another file. Whereas other API's are not affected.

Any ideas or suggestions? i have no idea on whats going on.

Error Message returned :

> cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)) //Appending extension 
>   TypeError: path.extname is not a function at DiskStorage.filename [as >getFilename] (/opt/backend/routes/subscription.route.js:42:32)

Thanks
-Vijay

Answer (score 0):

i found an solution finally, might help someone who is facing same issue in future.

i replaced headers which worked fine,

existing code:

```
let httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token
  })
}
```

New code :

```
let httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token
  })
}
```

And still no clue why it works now with this change.